Как убедиться что word-документ содержит разрыв страницы/раздела
У меня есть .docx содержащий разрывы страницы и разрыв раздела.
Мне надо программно убедиться, что они в нём есть.

При помощи org.apache.poi.poi-ooxml не выходит найти способ. Нашел com.deepoove.poi-tl содержащий в себе XWPFSection. Тоже не вижу рабочего решения. Просматривал BodyElements и Paragraphs, но не увидел ничего схожего внутри.
XWPFDocument docx = new XWPFDocument(Files.newInputStream(Paths.get(path)));
XWPFWordExtractor xwpfWordExtractor = new XWPFWordExtractor(docx);
for (IBodyElement bodyElement : xwpfWordExtractor.getDocument().getBodyElements()) {
    System.out.println(bodyElement.getElementType());    
    if (bodyElement instanceof XWPFSection) {
        System.out.println("Section break found.");
    }
}

Данный код не работает. Пробовал и с XWPFWordExtractor и без.
Другие варианты dependency - предлагать, интересны любые варианты.

С разрывом страниц вроде бы все просто — количество страниц, разрыв раздела тоже должен на него влиять, но без контекста задачи не понятно достаточно ли этого.

Да влияет очевидно, при получении метаданных документа отображается количество страниц "до разрыва раздела", а то что "после" будто бы не видит вообще.. но если получать просто весь текст документа, то достаётся весь текст. а вместо разрывов ставятся символы переноса строки...

Задача у меня следующая: получить текст документа и сравнить его с ожидаемым. Но меня не устраивает, что в строке не отображаются разрывы. Хочу убедиться, что разрыв страницы/раздела стоит на своём месте.

Можно реализовать перебор тела документа через XmlCursor.
Классы для поиска разрывов:

CTSectPr класс представляющий из себя  разрыв раздела <w:sectPr/>;
CTP класс представляющий из себя ряд элементов, один из которых может быть разрывом страницы <w:br w:type="page"/>.


XWPFDocument docx = new XWPFDocument(Files.newInputStream(Paths.get(path)));
CTBody body = docx.getDocument().getBody();
XmlCursor cursor = body.newCursor();
while (true) {
    XmlTokenSource token = cursor.getObject();
    if (token instanceof CTSectPr) {
        System.out.println("Разрыв секции обнаружен!");
    } else if (token instanceof CTP) {
        CTP paragraph = (CTP) token;
        if (paragraph.isSetRsidR() && paragraph.getRArray().length > 0) {
            paragraph.getRArray(0).getBrList().forEach(br -> {
                if (br.isSetType() && "page".equals(br.getType().toString())) {
                    System.out.println("Разрыв страницы обнаружен!");
                }
            });
        }
    }
    if (!cursor.hasNextToken()) break;
    cursor.toNextToken();
}


В конце документа по умолчанию есть конец раздела, поэтому счетчик "Добавленных" стоит вести с "-1"


Aspose.Words for Java

Нашел такой вариант решения, жаль мне не подходит потому что он платный.
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>AsposeJavaAPI</id>
        <name>Aspose Java API</name>
        <url>https://releases.aspose.com/java/repo/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>


<dependency>
    <groupId>com.aspose</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspose-words</artifactId>
    <version>22.11</version>
    <classifier>jdk17</classifier>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.aspose</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspose-words</artifactId>
    <version>22.11</version>
    <classifier>javadoc</classifier>
</dependency>


Document docx = new Document(path);
docx.getSections().get(0).getBody().getText()

Таким образом можно по каждой секции проверять текст, что решило бы мою задачу. Думаю в данной библиотеке можно найти и другой полезный функционал...

Смотреть на docx как на zip архив. Извлечь из него xml с контентом и парсить.

Такой мудрый вариант пока что не готов проверять, но выглядит тоже реалистично.

Разрыв страницы задаётся элементом <w:br w:type="page" /> в файле word\document.xml если рассмиатривать docx-файл как zip-архив.



Я не знаю, можно ли найти этот элемент приведёнными в вопросе библиотеками, но если нельзя, то я бы просто распаковал в памяти файл как zip-архив, добыл из него нужный файл и любым способом проверил наличие элемента (по css-селектору, xpath-селектору, или регуляркой).

да у меня был такой вариант как запасной, не лучшее решение, но я в своём ответе написал о его существовании
